# Unable to open a new tab using a button within a Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome Extension popup that will have some options in it: based on the selected one, I'll have to generate a URL and load it in a new tab. I've tried almost all the solutions I've found, but I'm still unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. I've provided the details below.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "New Extension",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "New Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
    "name": "New Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "permissions": [ "tabs" , "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 400px" bgcolor= "#FFFFFF">
    Operation:<input type="radio" name="operation" id="Google"     checked="checked">Google
    <input type="radio" name="operation" id="Yahoo">Yahoo<br/>
    <input type="button" name="btngenerate" id="btngenerate" value="Generate" />
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("btngenerate").addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("in generate URL");
    var URL = "http://google.com";
    if (document.getElementById("yahoo").checked == true) 
        URL = "http://yahoo.com";
    chrome.tabs.create({url: URL});
});
```

When I try to execute this, I'm able to see the popup, but, when I click on "Generate", nothing happens. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it's a _bad_ question for duplicate.

Comment: @Xan why not? Isn't this the exact same problem?

Comment: It is, but that question (the one I referenced) is _bad_ for not including any relevant code. I voted to actually close it now.

Comment: @Xan good point, this one is better worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome starts to parse your HTML file tag by tag and populates the DOM.

As soon as it encounters the `<script>` tag, it gets executed.

As a result, your code executes before `#btngenerate` exists in the DOM.

You need to wrap it in an event that will fire after the file is fully read and DOM is constructed:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("btngenerate").addEventListener(/*...*/);
});
```